# Wire.h missing - Failing to upload I2C 16x2 LCD sketch

Tags: i2c, lcd, wire-library

I am total newbie in Arduino and for the last 3 days I am trying to figure this out.

I would like to use an I2C display for a project. I have installed the LiquidCrystal_I2C, but when I try to upload it I get this `wire.h` missing message.

Could anyone please help me to understand and fix this?

[image]

Comment: +1 for saying `help me to understand` ......  too many people only want finished code

Comment: Please post code and error as text, not picture.

Comment: How do I post codes here?

Answer (score 2):

That library is special. It expects to be placed in the same location as the Wire library.  You need to find the location of the Wire library and place this library alongside it.  So you have:

```
.../Wire/Wire.cpp
.../Wire/Wire.h
.../LiquidCrystal_I2C/LiquidCrystal_I2C.cpp
.../LiquidCrystal_I2C/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h
```

etc

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I seems I have two copies of wire.cpp and wire.h in two different locations. Attached is a screenshot of their locations with respect to the LiquidCrystal_I2C.h and LiquidCrystal_I2C.cpp - is this the problem? 

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/n7m8UTR.png

Comment: Just pick one. If they're all the same then it won't matter which.

Comment: how can I pick one? (sorry if it's a stupid question)